# loop string and get value xslt

Tags: xslt, tokenize

I have html input file with that i need to process style information and design XSLT

```
<div style="width: 3%; min-width: 10px; padding: 0px;  border-color: black; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
```

i can get style value in XSLT variable, like below mention

```html
<xsl:variable name="width-col">
    <xsl:value-of select="@style"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

i don't know how to loop the string in foreach() and get width value out of it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to "loop string". Use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@style, 'width: '), ';')"/>
```